# Increase voltage output by connecting 2 PSU channels together

Tags: power-supply, voltage, switch-mode-power-supply

I have a 240W 24V switching power supply. It's a cheap chinese psu so there is no specification, only the info on the [ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/221316737065?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649) page.

It has 3 dc output channels and they seem to be individual channels and not just same output via different terminal pins (meaning it can output 24V to 3 different devices at the same time). I need 32-34V to power an led (via constant current driver). Is it possible to connect 2 of the 24V outputs to achieve 48V (34V with voltage adjusted to minimum of 17V possible by the psu )? If so how? I can imagine how you would connect the outputs in series...

Comment: Series should do the trick. I would also make sure that each of the voltage source channels have a decent capacitor on, size depending on your application. Just make sure that the channels are really separate, and do not share a common ground.

Comment: Are you sure that the three outputs have floating grounds and not a common ground for all three?

Comment: @alexan_e No, I am not really sure, how would I test for this? The reason I thought channels are separate is because I touched the + of one channel and - of another with multimeter probes and there was no voltage across it.

Comment: You can use an ohmmeter between grounds while the psu is off to check the resistance. You can also measure the voltage between the ground of one output and the ground of the other and  also the ground of one output and the positive of another output.

Comment: No spec usually means tears almost immediately or after a week or so. Build a boost regulator with constant current output and don't bother trying to 2nd guess what maybe going on inside the power supply.

Comment: @Andyaka What does tears mean exactly? I cant find any reference to it. I will be using buck constant current driver so cc is take care of, but voltage is too low to fully light up the led. Will probably have to just buy a 36V supply, boost regulators are half the price of the psu and building it is likely out of my knowledge and still probably not that cheap but if you add info on how to do it in an answer I will accept it. Also what about using 2 separate psu's in series (I have another one arriving soon)?

Comment: Tears as in sobs of dismay. Try  searching for boost led drivers. I'm  sure there are some. If, tomorrow I run across one I'll post it as an answer dude.

Comment: Since the ebay page you linked to just describes the supply as "24 Volt, 10 Amp", I'd assume that it is a single supply, possibly with multiple output terminals.  If it had multiple isolated outputs, I'd expect it to be decribed as "2 x 24 V 5 Amp", or otherwise explicitly indicating that it had separate isolated outputs.  If you have the supply, it should be easy to use a multimeter to determine its actual configuration.  How is the terminal strip labelled - that should be a good indication of the actual configuration.

Comment: @PeterBennet There doesn't seem to be any voltage reading between different COM and V+ channels. Terminal layout is like this from left: live, neutral, ground, com, com, com, V+, V+, V+

Comment: @Andyaka Why would there be Tears?? If you mean because psu failed then how would boost regulator change this? Issue with voltage converters is added price and loss of efficiency, if I cant use this psu I think it is a better idea to get a 36V psu instead of adding extra components...

Comment: If you need a 36V supply, you should buy one. I'll lay odds that is just a single 12V output (perhaps with a few parallel terminals).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Well, the output would b 36V so I don't really know what you mean by single 12V output..?

Answer (score 2):

It is highly doubtful if that supply has three separate outputs. Take an ohm meter and with the supply OFF measure resistance between each of the V+, V+ and V+ pins. I suspect that you will find them all bussed together.

Likewise use the ohm meter to measure resistance between the COM, COM and COM terminals. I suspect that you will find all three bussed together.

I give a strong indication of this being a single output supply because I zoomed in on the eBay picture that you pointed to and peeked through the screen cover. I could not see circuitry that would suggest a triple output unit.

Comment: I tried measuring but my multimeter is a crappy manual range and I got odd readings. at 200 range it measured 0.08 but at 2000M range I got 0.04 and 0 for other ranges so not sure what that means or maybe my multimeter is faulty...

Answer (score 0):

One better....the supply that you linked in the eBay listing page is certainly a single output power supply. The supply is the same unit as shown in these other two eBay listings.

[eBay1](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/CNC-Servo-Stepper-Motor-Driver-AC-DC-24V10A-240W-Switch-Power-Supply-110-220V-/251442968116?pt=UK_BOI_Industrial_Automation_Control_ET&hash=item3a8b2b3634)

[eBay2](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/24V-DC-10A-240W-Universal-AC-110-240V-Switching-Power-Supply-Silver-/231167707789?pt=UK_BOI_Electrical_Test_Measurement_Equipment_ET&hash=item35d2ab4a8d)

One of those other listings shows a model number sticker on the unit showing "DDH S-250-24". A quick search pulled up this [supplier page](http://chinaddh.gmc.globalmarket.com/products/details/24v-250w-non-waterproof-led-power-supply-295392.html) with that exact same supply. Check it out. It is a single output unit.